# mod_wsgi memory usage

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

We are serving over 100 sites with mod_wsgi process 2 thread 4 configuration.
Apache memory usage pushes limits of 15GB in this point how accurate to use mod_wsgi?

Anybody had tried other alternatives in a similar situation?

Comment: If you want help configuring Apache to use less memory, please ask this question on the mod_wsgi mailing list. SO is no good as a discussion forum and this is a topic which will involve a lot of discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I prefer to use fastcgi for multi-user sites. You get much better separation between users – separate processes, distinct user IDs, better resource allocation – I simply run "top" to figure out which customer has their server abused today.

Comment: Jacop Kaplan-Moss disagrees http://www.quora.com/Django/What-is-the-fastest-way-to-deploy-Django-with-FastCGI

Comment: The question doesn't state what kind of code they are running; fastcgi is a generic solution which obviously isn't suited for all workloads.

I haven't tested any alternatives (like gunicorn) yet, as fastcgi works quite well for the code on my servers.